# Is friends app not supported in ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: unity, facebook, 14.10, twitter, friends-app

I was using friends app till I updated to 14.10.I used to get notifications, Since I updated the feeds are not getting updated and I am not getting any notification from the app.

Is it not supported?

Comment: Tweeter feed is disabled in utopic. It is not supported any more.

Comment: Facebook is also not working. Why is it disabled?

Comment: Friends App & Freiends service are abandoned. You can a old build from source. Manually download & install from here (for i386): https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/friends/0.2.0+14.04.20140217.1-0ubuntu2/+build/6031820